# Vincular documentos pdf a registros

Tags: laravel-8

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Laravel-8 y en una sección de la aplicación debo de adjuntar 3 ficheros pdf por registro.

Me gustaría si es posible que me orientéis sobre cual sería la forma más optima de hacerlo por rendimiento (alojar los ficheros en el servidor y registrar en la dbase la ruta, serializar los ficheros...), o si me aconsejáis otra.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Siempre será mejor hacer un registro lógico (URL en la tabla, archivo a una carpeta del servidor) y servirlos usando una URL que no mapee la carpeta física en el servidor (sin dar a conocer la estructura interna de tu servidor). Esto es, por supuesto, una opinión; tu pregunta busca opiniones y por ello mismo es posible que termine cerrada.

Comment: Gracias por tú opinion, la tendré en cuenta.